# Why should java variable names start with lowercase characters?

Tags: java

I do not understand what the difference between

```
int Hello ;
```

and

```
int hello ;
```

is .

Does it make a big difference if i use upper case Characters ?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see ?. write a program

Comment: I tried it and nothing changed but I read that it is against "Javas Grammar "

Comment: It is a naming convention.

Comment: If `Hello` were an object, this would not work as it would be referencing the class object. `Hello hello = new Hello()` If Hello is not defined, then yes, this woruld work, it is just a guideline to follow for ease of readability. I interpet names beginning with an uppercase letter as a class object.

Comment: oh ok nice thank you

Comment: It's an *extremely* strong naming convention.

Comment: @TheLostMind: the OP asked about variable names starting with a lowercase or uppercase character, not camel casing of method names. And I would not regard any answer in the linked question as answer to the OP question.

Comment: @wero - Did you read *Bill's* answer to that question?. Its a convention. I don't think having an answer like *its a convention* makes sense here

Comment: `Hello.doSomething()` ... is `Hello` an object or a class? Is `doSomething()` an object method or a static method? If you would have followed the convention, then you could answer these questions very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of Java Convention!
Actually, you can write a program like the way you're imagining but, you won't be following any pattern.......If you become a real programmer someday, you'll understand that patterns exist to make things better and easier.....